# Certain Etsy API calls don't work on Azure

Tags: azure, tomcat, etsy

I'm using the `Etsy API` to get products on a `Tomcat7` server deployed on `Azure`. Most of the time it just works but when I go for a certain subcategory I get no results back.

The weird thing is that on my developer machine it works and I do get back results.

How is that possible? How do I even start debugging this? Again, for some categories the call works both on my developer machine and Azure, but for others it only works on my developer machine.

This is the URL that is causing the problem:

```
https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings/active?&api_key=myapikey&keywords=star+&limit=24&offset=0&sort_on=created&sort_order=down&category=Vintage%2FJewelry
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that when I created the URL I used Java's `File.separator` to separate between two parts of the URL. It worked on my OSX machine because `File.separator` is "/" and that's fine. But on Azure's windows servers `File.separator` is "\" - and it breaks the URL.

The lesson: think before writing code. Don't do it on autopilot.